# Reliable HFS+ Journaled mount in any OS for ARMv6

Tags: linux-kernel, hfs+, arm, darwin, netbsd

I need an operating system for ARMv6 (Raspberry Pi) that can reliably mount HFS+ Journaled as read/write, with volume sizes up to 16TB.

I've not been able to find details on how stable HFS+ Journaled is in the latest versions of the Linux Kernel.

According to a possibly outdated Wikipedia article, there are several issues with HFS+ Journaled in Linux but work is underway to resolve this:

"As of February 2011, work is in progress to lift this restriction"
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=HFS_Plus&oldid=549625057#Linux

I've also looked into using Darwin or NetBSD as Apple uses these so hoped there would be an official driver, but no luck:

- I can't find a way to compile Darwin for the Raspberry Pi as Apple haven't released the source code for ARM, and http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwin-arm/ seems to have been removed
- As far as I can tell, Apple haven't released the NetBSD HFS+ drivers used on the Apple Airport

Can anyone answer

1. Are the stability issues of HFS+ in Linux fixed? (and how I can track this?)
2. If it's still unstable, can anyone recommend a stable alternative?

Comment: Perhaps of note is this conversation on the linux-fsdevel list, where someone is looking at getting Netgear's HFS+ code working with the Linux kernel - don't think this was resolved though. http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg57099.html

Comment: I have only seen read/write with HFS+ in linux if Journaling is disabled (reliably)...  Why are you tied to using HFS+ with linux instead of a traditional linux formatting (or at least a system that has had long tested stability with linux)?

Comment: 1. I have an existing large partition that would be a lot of work to migrate (partly because I don't have a second device with that much space to backup), 2. because I want to be able to swap the device between my Mac and the Raspberry Pi in the future

Comment: This doesn't seem to be suited for [SF] since it's missing the professional workplace context.

Answer (score 3):

- The stability issues of HFS+ (non journaled) were mainly about accessing drives > 2TB. This limit was removed at the end of June 2011.
- Open bugs can be tracked at [bugzilla.kernel.org](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=hfs).
- Discussions and patches for HFS+ on Linux are submitted to [the linux-fsdevel list](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/).
- Changes to the HFS+ source code can be tracked at [git.kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/fs/hfsplus/).
- There is still no Journal support, but a recent experimental kernel extension is available at [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net/hfsplusdkms).
- This project is linked to the [following 'bug' in Ubuntu](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.15/+bug/49052) (considered a bug as HFS+ Journaled was previously accepted as a feature in Ubuntu [and marked complete](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/5878/)).
- Paragon make [proprietary drivers for Linux](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-professional/), but they don't support ARM.
- They also make [drivers for Android that do compile on ARM](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-hfs-android/).